# How to implement Undo and Redo feature in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement Undo and Redo feature in as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672166/how-to-implement-undo-and-redo-feature-in-as3)

I am going to create an application in that i have to implement an **Undo and Redo** feature.
In the application there will be multiple objects located on stage and user can customize 
the position of the objects. But when user clicks on Undo the object go back to their default 
position and after clicking on redo object will move on the new position.

So my question is how can i apply these feature in my application? 
Is there any library or any third party classes?

Can some one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google turned this up: http://blog.alanklement.com/2009/09/17/as3-undo-redo-with-display-objects/

Comment: Also this probably gets better responses on stackoverflow.

Comment: It's not AS3, but what we are doing (for a LOB application) is using a list of transactions (each containing a set of atomic transactions) and a pointer/index to the current 'head' (think of it like a Git head) in the transaction list; undo/redo is merely a matter of rolling forwards and backwards.

Comment: This is not specific to game development. Migrating to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713172/actionscript-general-undo-redo-api

Comment: yeah!! actully this is an important question for me and thats why i was asked this gamedev.stackexchange.com too. But someone migrated it with stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed like a fun exercise.  The following tracks start and end coordinates of display objects, supports undo/redo and destroys redo actions when a new movement is made.  It's probably a bit simple and restrictive for your needs, but could be easily extended by adding to the VO.

HistoryVO:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    public class HistoryVO {

        public var mc:DisplayObject;
        public var oldX:Number;
        public var oldY:Number;
        public var newX:Number;
        public var newY:Number;

        public function HistoryVO($mc:DisplayObject,$oldX:Number,$oldY:Number)
        {
            mc = $mc;
            oldX = $oldX;
            oldY = $oldY;
        }
    }
}
```

HistoryManager:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    public class HistoryManager {

        private var historyList:Vector.<HistoryVO>;

        private var tempVO:HistoryVO;

        private var index:int;

        public function HistoryManager() 
        {
            //initialize the list
            historyList = new Vector.<HistoryVO>();
            index = -1;
        }

        public function createEntry($mc:DisplayObject,$oldX:Number,$oldY:Number):void
        {
            //create a tempory VO to store the old position and the object
            tempVO = new HistoryVO($mc,$oldX,$oldY);
        }

        public function finishEntry($mc:DisplayObject,$newX:Number,$newY:Number):void
        {
            //make sure this is the same object
            if($mc == tempVO.mc) {
                tempVO.newX = $newX;
                tempVO.newY = $newY;
                if(historyList.length > index+1) {
                    //delete any future history
                    historyList = historyList.splice(0,index+1);
                }
                historyList.push(tempVO);
                index++;
            } else {
                throw new Error("Target DisplayObject does not match the stored value");
            }
        }

        //redo
        public function nextStep():void
        {
            if(historyList.length > index+1) {
                var step:HistoryVO = historyList[++index];
                step.mc.x = step.newX;
                step.mc.y = step.newY;
            }
        }

        //undo
        public function previousStep():void
        {
            if(index > -1) {
                var step:HistoryVO = historyList[index--];
                step.mc.x = step.oldX;
                step.mc.y = step.oldY;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example document class:

```
package  {

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        private var history:HistoryManager;

        private var movies:Vector.<Sprite>;

        private var backBut:Sprite;
        private var nextBut:Sprite;

        public function Main() 
        {
            history = new HistoryManager();
            movies = new Vector.<Sprite>();
            (stage) ? init() : addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        }

        private function init(evt:Event = null):void
        {
            //create some sprites to play with
            for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                movies[i] = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;
                movies[i].x = Math.round(Math.random() * 500);
                movies[i].y = Math.round(Math.random() * 350);
                movies[i].graphics.beginFill(Math.round(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF));
                movies[i].graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
                movies[i].graphics.endFill();
                movies[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onDown);
                movies[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUp);
            }
            //create the buttons
            backBut = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;
            backBut.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            backBut.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,30);
            backBut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,previousStep);
            nextBut = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;
            nextBut.x = 110;
            nextBut.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
            nextBut.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,30);
            nextBut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nextStep);
        }

        private function onDown(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            history.createEntry(Sprite(evt.target),evt.target.x,evt.target.y);
            evt.target.startDrag();
        }

        private function onUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            evt.target.stopDrag();
            history.finishEntry(Sprite(evt.target),evt.target.x,evt.target.y);
        }

        private function previousStep(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            history.previousStep();
        }

        private function nextStep(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            history.nextStep();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx but dont you think that this one only works for one object?

Comment: no, it works for as many display objects as you push into it.  This is a complete application, compile it and have a go.

Comment: thanks man!! u gave me another idea...:)

Comment: i have another question about coldfusion and as3.. Please have a look. thanx..:)

Comment: Sadly I don't know much about ColdFusion

Comment: not an issue, thanx for ur response..:)

Answer (score 6):

[Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) is used for situations like this. A quick Google search yielded [an article](http://blog.alanklement.com/2009/09/17/as3-undo-redo-with-display-objects/) which explains how it is implemented.

Comment: this is only for single object. what to do when we have multiple objects on stage.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you didn't mention whether you use the flex framework. If it is so, this **flex library** may be helpful:

http://code.google.com/p/flexundoredo/

If the library is not suitable, you can provide your own implementation using **the command pattern**:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: i am not using flex framework. it is flash as3